# Include HTML (Bootstrap Modal Box) with a plugin into my header

Tags: plugin-development, filters, actions, html, wp-head

I want to include some HTML, spezific a bootstrap modal box.

This is my function with the HTML part:

```
public function dmd_fav_modal_box() {

   $content = '<div class="modal fade" id="dmd_favorite_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dmd_favorite_modalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Test</p>
                </div>
                <!--div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>';
    return $content;
}
```

In my constructor I tried some filter and actions.

E.g.

```
add_action( 'wp_head',  array($this, 'dmd_fav_modal_box') );
add_filter( 'the_content',  array($this, 'dmd_fav_modal_box') );
```

But nothing works. Can somebody help me?

Comment: "Nothing works" say very little about the problem; the most we can do is start guessing what is happening. Can you be more explicit about the problem you have? Can you include a code which we can use to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need the_content filter to add the modal, but bootstrap.js is needed to make it work.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueue_bootstrap');

public function enqueue_bootstrap(){
    wp_register_script( 'bootstrap', plugins_url( 'your-plugin/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap' );
}
```

EDIT:

You need to add $content argument to your function.
As the codex says

> Note that the filter function must return the content after it is finished processing, or site visitors will see a blank page and other plugins also filtering the content may generate errors.

in your case:

```
public function dmd_fav_modal_box($content) {

    $modal = '<div class="modal fade" id="dmd_favorite_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dmd_favorite_modalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Test</p>
            </div>
            <!--div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>';
return $modal.$content;
```

Comment: bootstrap is included. It works if I include the modal HTML in the header.php. But I want to include the HTML automatically with my plugin.

Comment: echo $content; instead of return.

Answer (score 0):

Just in **__construct** add this **add add_action('wp_footer', ''array( $this, 'dmd_fav_modal_box') );** then html part will be added to footer section and should work, also not sure, because when You added it in **wp_head** it also should work but this solution is not recommended. Are You able to post here all class ?